# Running `mypy` on a project with `pysnmp-lextudio` package dependency returns `named-defined` errors

Tags: python, mypy, type-hinting, python-poetry, pysnmp

To recreate the issue I am having:

```bash
poetry new pysnmp-and-mypy
cd ./pysnmp-and-mypy
poetry add mypy
poetry add pysnmp-lextudio
touch ./pysnmp_and_mypy/test.py
```

Put the following code into `./pysnmp_and_mypy/test.py`:

```py
from pysnmp.hlapi import *  # type: ignore
from typing import Any


def convert_snmp_type_to_python_type(
    snmp_value: Integer32 | Integer | Unsigned32 | Gauge32 | OctetString | Any,
) -> int | str:
    match snmp_value:
        case Integer32():
            return int(snmp_value)
        case Integer():
            return int(snmp_value)
        case Unsigned32():
            return int(snmp_value)
        case Gauge32():
            return int(snmp_value)
        case OctetString():
            return str(snmp_value)
        case _:
            raise TypeError(
                "Only SNMP types of type integer and string are supported. Received type of {}".format(
                    str(type(snmp_value))
                )
            )


def get_data(ip_address: str, object_identity: str) -> int | str:
    iterator = getCmd(
        SnmpEngine(),
        CommunityData("public", mpModel=0),
        UdpTransportTarget((ip_address, 161)),
        ContextData(),
        ObjectType(ObjectIdentity(object_identity)),
    )

    error_indication, error_status, error_index, variable_bindings = next(iterator)

    if error_indication:
        raise RuntimeError(error_indication.prettyPrint())
    elif error_status:
        raise RuntimeError(error_status.prettyPrint())
    else:
        [variable_binding] = variable_bindings
        [_oid, value] = variable_binding
        return convert_snmp_type_to_python_type(value)
```

Run:

```bash
poetry install
poetry run mypy ./pysnmp_and_mypy
```

Now observe that the following errors are returned:

```
pysnmp_and_mypy\test.py:6: error: Name "Integer32" is not defined  [name-defined]
pysnmp_and_mypy\test.py:6: error: Name "Integer" is not defined  [name-defined]
pysnmp_and_mypy\test.py:6: error: Name "Unsigned32" is not defined  [name-defined]
pysnmp_and_mypy\test.py:6: error: Name "Gauge32" is not defined  [name-defined]
pysnmp_and_mypy\test.py:6: error: Name "OctetString" is not defined  [name-defined]
pysnmp_and_mypy\test.py:9: error: Name "Integer32" is not defined  [name-defined]
pysnmp_and_mypy\test.py:11: error: Name "Integer" is not defined  [name-defined]
pysnmp_and_mypy\test.py:13: error: Name "Unsigned32" is not defined  [name-defined]
pysnmp_and_mypy\test.py:15: error: Name "Gauge32" is not defined  [name-defined]
pysnmp_and_mypy\test.py:17: error: Name "OctetString" is not defined  [name-defined]
pysnmp_and_mypy\test.py:28: error: Name "getCmd" is not defined  [name-defined]
pysnmp_and_mypy\test.py:29: error: Name "SnmpEngine" is not defined  [name-defined]
pysnmp_and_mypy\test.py:30: error: Name "CommunityData" is not defined  [name-defined]
pysnmp_and_mypy\test.py:31: error: Name "UdpTransportTarget" is not defined  [name-defined]
pysnmp_and_mypy\test.py:32: error: Name "ContextData" is not defined  [name-defined]
pysnmp_and_mypy\test.py:33: error: Name "ObjectType" is not defined  [name-defined]
pysnmp_and_mypy\test.py:33: error: Name "ObjectIdentity" is not defined  [name-defined]
```

How do I get rid of these errors in the appropriate way? Why isn't MyPy finding the definitions? They are definitely there, as the code runs just fine and Pylance doesn't have an issue finding them. If there isn't a good way, what is the best workaround?

Note that I had to do `from pysnmp.hlapi import * # type: ignore` because I otherwise get the error `error: Skipping analyzing "pysnmp.hlapi": module is installed, but missing library stubs or py.typed marker  [import-untyped]`.

Comment: Pylance has an option called [`python.analysis.useLibraryCodeForTypes`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/python/pylance-introduces-five-new-features-that-enable-type-magic-for-python-developers/#5-py-typed-files-are-now-respected-when-using-the-uselibrarycodefortypes-setting), which should be turned on for you. mypy does not have an equivalent option, so libraries which aren't [PEP 561 compliant](https://peps.python.org/pep-0561/#packaging-type-information) (like `pysnmp`) will behave like what you have here. The simplest solution is to add `py.typed` in the `pysnmp` directory.

Comment: Thank you for the information. However, I am confused, as I thought it was `# type: ignore` that was telling MyPy to not worry that `pysnmp` doesn't have types defined. And the errors don't mention anything about types. They're claiming that the names don't even exist, which is wrong. If it was complaining about types, I'd understand better. I don't see any mention of `name-defined` errors here: https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/running_mypy.html#missing-imports.

Comment: Star-import from untyped package is a big trouble for `mypy` (and usually some trouble for you and other tooling, no matter whether package is typed). Consider explicit imports. If you need same set in _many_ files, at least do (future?) yourself a favour, write explicit import in your own file once and then import from it instead of external library - this will please `mypy` and prevent you from unexpected namespacing issues later.

Comment: In short, `mypy` doesn't know that you have `Integer` in scope, because your star import was from untyped package - `mypy` thinks your namespace remains empty after this import, AFAIC.

Comment: @bmitc the "missing imports" documentation says "*...mypy will assume the type of that module is Any, the dynamic type. This means attempting to access any attribute of the module will automatically succeed.*" You've used a star import on a module on which mypy refuses (!) to have any knowledge of existence of module variables, which is why you're getting those errors. In short: mypy needs to have an equivalent option as Pylance, but without it, you'll have to add a `py.typed` file to the `pysnmp` directory.

Comment: @dROOOze such option would be terrible unless it's fine-grained (allowing some **selection** of modules to process this way). Many packages are not typing-friendly, and you'd better keep getting `Any` imported from them instead of mysterious errors due to "maintainers never tried to make `mypy` accept this gibberish". (surprise, it's now roughly equivalent to `touch path/to/module/py.typed`)

Comment: @STerliakov Depends on the degree of checking. No matter how untyped a library is, they can't lie to a type checker about the existence of nominal types and their inheritance tree (`class` declarations), function definitions, and function signature arities. For classes, mypy can just pretend that all untyped library's classes have all existing methods, but have no instance attributes and a `__getattr__` method, and it'll be a lot more useful already.

Comment: Thank you both for your help! In this case, I have simply explicitly imported all types and functions, and this has seemed to make MyPy happy (see this posted in an answer). I haven't tried it, but it seems the other possibility seems to be to use `stubgen` to generate all the type stubs for `pysnmp-lextudio`, which is an external library, and then point MyPy to these stubs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution, garnered from the helpful comments in the original question, is to explicitly import all used types and functions. In this case, the following allows MyPy to pass.

```py
from pysnmp.hlapi import (  # type: ignore
    Integer32,
    Integer,
    Unsigned32,
    Gauge32,
    OctetString,
    Integer32,
    Integer,
    Unsigned32,
    Gauge32,
    OctetString,
    SnmpEngine,
    ObjectType,
    ObjectIdentity,
    SnmpEngine,
    ObjectType,
    ObjectIdentity,
    Integer,
    getCmd,
    setCmd,
    CommunityData,
    UdpTransportTarget,
    ContextData,
)
```

Note that I still needed to provide the ignore comment for the first line to get rid of the error:

```
error: Skipping analyzing "pysnmp.hlapi": module is installed, but missing library stubs or py.typed marker  [import-untyped]
note: See https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/running_mypy.html#missing-imports
```

It appears this ignore comment is explicitly the line that contains it, as placing it after the import "block" (on the line with the closing parentheses does not work and additionally yields an `error: Unused "type: ignore" comment [unused-ignore]"`.

Comment: I experimented with creating type stubs with `stubgen`, but I never bothered to point `mypy` to them to test them out since the above solution worked. So I'm going to mark this as the solution here.